# Import csv " vs '

Tags: powershell, csv, apostrophe

I was wondering what the difference between me putting the quotes or the apostrophe over the import process. I am a powershell novice and was just looking to see what the difference is

```
$csv = Import-Csv 'C:\Users\eh3599\Desktop\Powershell CSV Test\Local Group Members.csv' |

$csv = Import-Csv "C:\Users\eh3599\Desktop\Powershell CSV Test\Testnumberone.csv" |
```

What is the difference between the quotes and the apostrophe, and will if affect my code if I use one or the other?

Comment: here. let me google that for you. http://windowsitpro.com/blog/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-powershell-whats-difference and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes do not allow [string interpolation](http://www.powershellish.com/blog/2014-12-09-strings-expansion), while double quotes do.

```
$test = "some string"
Write-Host "Some sentence, $test."
```

Output:

> Some sentence, **some string**.

```
$test = 'some string'
Write-Host 'Some sentence, $test.'
```

Output:

> Some sentence, **$test**.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to supporting string expansion, double quotes allows you to run script blocks/commands before the string is output to its destination.

e.g.

```
Write "$(Get-Date -UFormat $Format) This $Thing happened at $($Thing.time)"
```

As a best practice, I stick to single-quotes when I do not need any substitutions in the string.